# Google-colab install fails on "Running setup.py install for pandas ... error"

Tags: python, installation, google-colaboratory

I'm trying to install google-colab via pip, but it errors out here:

```
Running setup.py install for pandas ... error
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1
```

I have pandas already installed, so I also tried to install google-colab with --ignore-installed but it still results with the same error. How do I fix this error? Thx